# key="value"&key="value" String parsing in Java

Tags: java, android

How can I parse a string like 
`success="true"&sign_type="RSA"&sign="xxx"`

("" is included in the original string) into a Map or JavaBean?

Comment: it looks like a query string . What have you tried on coding ?

Comment: I got the string from a http response and I wanna check out the value of say, success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
String[] arr = str.split("&");
for (String s : arr) {
    String[] a = s.split("=");
    map.put(a[0], a[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uri uri=Uri.parse(url_string);
uri.getQueryParameter("RSA");

Comment: Please don't waste your time answering duplicate questions. Someone else with a new question may be loosing the chance to get your help.

Answer (score -1):

string.split(String regex) will be your friend here.